# How do I get the offset coordinates of a container in react.js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a class component which renders a container. I would like to print the offset of that container within the container. The react code below should explain what I am trying to do:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div onPointerDownCapture={this.started} onPointerLeave={this.ended} onPointerUpCapture={this.ended} onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove} className='gesture-view'>
        {this.state.x || this.state.y ? "The mouse is at x: " + (this.state.x) + ", y: " + (this.state.y) : "Move the mouse over this box"}
        {"This is the offset: "container.offsetX}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Fundamentally I want to create a container which contains text describing the position of the container relative to the entire visible view. I set the position and width of the container inside of css.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper). The `div` element will be available as the `current` property on the ref in `componentDidMount` (for the first render) and `componentDidUpdate` (for subsequent ones).

You create the ref via `createRef`, usually in the constructor:

```
this.divRef = React.createRef();
```

then in the lifecycle methods described above, you can use `this.divRef.current` to get the position. You can either set the position in state (after first checking that the values have changed), which will cause a new render, or directly insert the text into the `div` via `this.divRef.current.textContent = ...` or similar.

Here's an example using `textContent`:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.divRef = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.showContainerOffset();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.showContainerOffset();
    }

    showContainerOffset() {
        const {current} = this.divRef;
        if (!current) {
            return;
        }
        // Or put them in state, which will cause a re-render if they change
        current.textContent =
            `The container is at ${current.offsetLeft}, ${current.offsetTop}`;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container" ref={this.divRef} />
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<div>
    <Example />
    <Example />
</div>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Here's an example using state:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            offsetLeft: NaN,
            offsetTop:  NaN,
        };
        this.divRef = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.showContainerOffset();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.showContainerOffset();
    }

    showContainerOffset() {
        const {current} = this.divRef;
        if (!current) {
            return;
        }
        const {offsetLeft, offsetTop} = current;
        this.setState(prev => {
            if (offsetLeft !== prev.offsetLeft ||
                offsetTop  !== prev.offsetTop) {
                return {offsetLeft, offsetTop};
            }
            return null;
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {offsetLeft, offsetTop} = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="container" ref={this.divRef}>
                {isNaN(offsetLeft) ? null : `The container is at ${offsetLeft}, ${offsetTop}`}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<div>
    <Example />
    <Example />
</div>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```